# Keeping array of objects and child object in sync in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm pretty new to Angular, Ionic, etc but have a question about keeping an array of objects in sync.

Say that I have a provider called Devices like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Devices {

  public devices: any;  

...
```

Now in one of my components I grab one of the objects inside of devices and update an attribute:

```
import { Devices } from '../../providers/devices/devices';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-device-list',
  templateUrl: 'device-list.html',
})
export class DeviceListPage {

  device: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
      public devices: Device) {

this.device = this.devices.devices[0];
this.device.name = "A new name";
...
```

The problem is that `this.device` is a local reference to the object.  I want to be able to keep these local objects in sync with the global object in the service (`Devices.devices`) so that when I update a local reference I can also update the value inside the Devices provider so that other components utilizing that provider will be updated.

Is there an "angular" way of doing this or do I need to write some kind of `setDevice` function inside of the provider that rebuilds the `devices` array with the new value for `device?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are accessed by reference. So if you access the object in your service directly or assign the object itself to a local variable instead of assigning it's property to a local variable, it will be in sync. The other option is to use `Object.assign()` every time you make a change.

**Update:** Here is a small example to quickly see how objects work in JS

```
var a  = {
 name: "John",
 age: 30
}
var b = a;

b.name = "Smith";

console.log(a.name);

let c = a;

let d = c.name;
d = "Mikey";

console.log(c.name, a.name, b.name);
```

Here a, b, and c all point to the same object, so if you change the name in any case, all three references are affected. `d` however is not pointing to the object. It is only storing the name property and changing it won't change the original Object. **JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/owr6fmub/1/

So you can store the object again locally - it will create another reference and it will be in sync. However, storing an object property locally won't change the main object. They won't be in sync.

The same goes for Arrays. Arrays are objects in Javascript.

Comment: Right so if I set let device = this.devices.devices[0] then any changes to device wont be reflered back into the devices obect right?

Comment: It should still be in sync since it's a reference to the object at index 0. Does this not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.devices.devices[0].name = "A new name"
```

I think this will be Ok.

You can also use

> BehaviorSubject

To notice other component that devices has been changed.